# Can we add an 'overstay' tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have seen a few questions that mention overstaying a visa, and it's exactly the kind of thing people might search for on this board - e.g. applying for citizenship, would a previous overstay harm my application, that kind of thing.

I was just retagging a few questions, and was going to add this tag but found that it's not in the system. And I can't (yet?) add tags myself, so I would like to ask:

Can we add an 'overstay' tag to assist people in finding such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that seems reasonable. Ideally you would either edit this question, or provide an answer, with a list of questions to tag, a tag wiki execerpt, and tag wiki.

Comment: I'm happy to tag the questions myself - I retag questions often. The issue is that there isn't an 'overstay' tag, and I don't know how to add one.

Comment: @ScottEarle far as I've seen on StackExchange, you don't need to create the tag before adding it to a question. Just add it to a question by typing it and pressing <space> instead of clicking on an already-existing tag.  It should be created automatically.

Comment: Ah. Time for a sheepish grin, then. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottEarle [finally found it.](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) It *is* a privilege, but on this site at the moment it requires only 150 reputation.

Answer (score 3):

I accepted your retag requests, so the [overstay](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overstay) tag should be live. If you can please add an excerpt / tag-wiki as well.